# Is it possible to get already-filled answers before form submit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm searching for a possibility, to get the already-filled response content of the first form TextItem (i.e. surname) before the submit button is pressed.

The reason behind is:

- just before the submit button, I ask the user to open a GAS web app, via a hyperlink
- inside that web app I would need the surname, which should be already completed by user

I've already unsuccessfully tried the following:

- tried to get the Form by both `getActiveForm()` and `openByUrl(url)`
- to get the FromResponse by `getResponses()` and `getResponse(responseId)`
- and at last called `getResponseForItem(item)`
- but no combination of the upper seems to work...

After those failed attempts I'm assuming the following:

- it is possible either only inside the on-form-submit event handler via passed argument
- or only when the response is created by the script

Have I done something wrong?

Could anyone give me another solution?
(or confirm me that it is really not possible)

Comment: Yes, it is very similar. Still, for me, it wasn't clear if the introduced data cannot be accessed at all, or if only the manipulation of form items is not possible via GAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to affect a form with app script until after it has been submitted.

Comment: I've tried many options/workarounds and since none has been successful I have marked this answer as solution.